# How do you use data binding to create a TreeView with infinite depth in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I need to create a TreeView with an infinite parent-child hierarchy. The TreeView needs to be bound to a list named `ResourceList` and draws its child resources from a list named `Children`. All the items are the same type.

Here is the XAML code I have so far:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceList}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ResourcesTree" SelectedItemChanged="ResourcesTree_OnSelectedItemChanged" Margin="0,4,0,0">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

It works, but the problem is, it only goes three levels deep. What should I change to make it infinite?

In case it's important, I'm using C# and .NET for the code-behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Treeview should look like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceList}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ResourcesTree" SelectedItemChanged="ResourcesTree_OnSelectedItemChanged" Margin="0,4,0,0">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type childType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierachicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Note `childType` should be whatever class your tree is made up of.

The important part is the `DataType="{x:Type childType}"` which makes sure that all children (and grandchildren, etc..) use this datatemplate and it handles hierarchical aspect of it for you

Comment: Thanks! It worked! That turned out to be really simple, so I'm surprised my attempts to Google search it didn't get the proper results.

Comment: Yeah the first time I tried using a TreeView it took me forever to figure it out. WPF does all the heavy lifting for you, its nice